# Handle nested JSON data using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following nested json data file.
Here the link to the data file: we.tl/t-GluETOhQV9

[image]

I would like to read it with libraries like Pandas.
When I use the commands:

```
with open(data_file.json') as json_file:
    data = pd.read_json(json_file, orient='index')
```

I have the error:

> `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'.`

How can I avoid that?
Thanks

Comment: No sorry. My file looks like this:

Comment: data = [
    {
        "{'X(A)':0.3,'X(B)':0.1,'X(C)':0.6}":{
            'FCC':0.4,
            'BCC':0.6
        },
        "{'X(A)':0.5,'X(B)':0.2,'X(C)':0.3}":{
            'L12':0.2,
            'BCC':0.25,
            'FCC':0.55
        }
    }
]

Comment: Are data confidental? If not, is possible share `json` file?

Comment: Sure, I just put the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can processing each dictionary in loop by expand keys converted to dictionary with values and then pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import json, ast

with open ('data_file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    # print (data)
    
out = [{**ast.literal_eval(k), **v} for x in data for k, v in x.items()]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(out)
print (df)
           X(Al)         X(Ti)  X(Co)  X(Cr)  X(Fe)  FCC_L12#1  FCC_L12#3  \
0   1.000000e-07  1.000000e-07   0.25   0.25   0.25   1.000000        NaN   
1   1.000000e-07  2.000008e-02   0.23   0.23   0.23   0.983281   0.016719   
2   1.000000e-07  4.000006e-02   0.21   0.21   0.21   0.890292        NaN   
3   1.000000e-07  6.000004e-02   0.19   0.19   0.19   0.797599   0.202401   
4   1.000000e-07  8.000002e-02   0.17   0.17   0.17   0.705188   0.294812   
5   1.000000e-07  1.000000e-01   0.15   0.15   0.15   0.613059        NaN   
6   2.000008e-02  1.000000e-07   0.23   0.23   0.23   1.000000        NaN   
7   2.000008e-02  2.000008e-02   0.21   0.21   0.21   0.916265        NaN   
8   2.000008e-02  4.000006e-02   0.19   0.19   0.19   0.812095   0.187905   
9   2.000008e-02  6.000004e-02   0.17   0.17   0.17   0.716068        NaN   
10  2.000008e-02  8.000002e-02   0.15   0.15   0.15   0.622758        NaN   
11  2.000008e-02  1.000000e-01   0.13   0.13   0.13   0.530515        NaN   
12  4.000006e-02  1.000000e-07   0.21   0.21   0.21   0.982741        NaN   
13  4.000006e-02  2.000008e-02   0.19   0.19   0.19   0.862430        NaN   
14  4.000006e-02  4.000006e-02   0.17   0.17   0.17   0.743688        NaN   
15  4.000006e-02  6.000004e-02   0.15   0.15   0.15   0.640353        NaN   
16  4.000006e-02  8.000002e-02   0.13   0.13   0.13   0.543365   0.456635   
17  4.000006e-02  1.000000e-01   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.449275   0.550725   
18  6.000004e-02  1.000000e-07   0.19   0.19   0.19   0.920498        NaN   
19  6.000004e-02  2.000008e-02   0.17   0.17   0.17   0.802916        NaN   
20  6.000004e-02  4.000006e-02   0.15   0.15   0.15   0.673811        NaN   
21  6.000004e-02  6.000004e-02   0.13   0.13   0.13   0.564263   0.435737   
22  6.000004e-02  8.000002e-02   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.463467        NaN   
23  6.000004e-02  1.000000e-01   0.09   0.09   0.09   0.367051        NaN   
24  8.000002e-02  1.000000e-07   0.17   0.17   0.17   0.864677        NaN   
25  8.000002e-02  2.000008e-02   0.15   0.15   0.15   0.727421        NaN   
26  8.000002e-02  4.000006e-02   0.13   0.13   0.13   0.597104        NaN   
27  8.000002e-02  6.000004e-02   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.483931   0.516069   
28  8.000002e-02  8.000002e-02   0.09   0.09   0.09   0.380282   0.619718   
29  8.000002e-02  1.000000e-01   0.07   0.07   0.07   0.281743   0.718257   
30  1.000000e-01  1.000000e-07   0.15   0.15   0.15   0.815093        NaN   
31  1.000000e-01  2.000008e-02   0.13   0.13   0.13   0.637194        NaN   
32  1.000000e-01  4.000006e-02   0.11   0.11   0.11   0.509993        NaN   
33  1.000000e-01  6.000004e-02   0.09   0.09   0.09   0.396467        NaN   
34  1.000000e-01  8.000002e-02   0.07   0.07   0.07   0.291342   0.708658   
35  1.000000e-01  1.000000e-01   0.05   0.05   0.05   0.191109   0.808891   

    FCC_L12#2  BCC_B2#2  
0         NaN       NaN  
1         NaN       NaN  
2    0.109708       NaN  
3         NaN       NaN  
4         NaN       NaN  
5    0.386941       NaN  
6         NaN       NaN  
7    0.083735       NaN  
8         NaN       NaN  
9    0.283932       NaN  
10   0.377242       NaN  
11   0.469485       NaN  
12        NaN  0.017259  
13   0.137570       NaN  
14   0.256312       NaN  
15   0.359647       NaN  
16        NaN       NaN  
17        NaN       NaN  
18        NaN  0.079502  
19   0.197084       NaN  
20   0.326189       NaN  
21        NaN       NaN  
22   0.536533       NaN  
23   0.632949       NaN  
24        NaN  0.135323  
25   0.258054  0.014525  
26   0.402896       NaN  
27        NaN       NaN  
28        NaN       NaN  
29        NaN       NaN  
30        NaN  0.184907  
31   0.330386  0.032419  
32   0.490007       NaN  
33   0.603533       NaN  
34        NaN       NaN  
35        NaN       NaN
```